# Momentum and angular momentum during a car turn

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, momentum, conservation-laws

Imagine a car speeds up to some speed then shuts off the engine, then does a 90 degree turn, then moves forward again without ever switching the engine back on, so that any steering is done only with the steering wheel. It would seem to have gained forward momentum (before the turn by engine power), then lost it and gained angular momentum (during the turn), then lost angular momentum and gained linear momentum in a different direction than the start (after the turn). Where is this momentum & angular momentum coming from and where did they go (since momentum & angular momentum cannot be converted into each other)?

Comment: Hint: what do you think will happen if the car is on a slippery road? When the wheels turn, will the car turn?

Comment: _"since momentum & angular momentum cannot be converted into each other"_: Not exactly, the former does affect the latter most of the time. Read the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_momentum), on either **3D** or **2D** angular momentum, depending on which one you want (the calculations are a bit different). Here's another [website](https://www.dummies.com/education/science/physics/how-to-calculate-angular-momentum/) if the wiki is too wordy.

Comment: @SnipingPoodle I can understand that linear momentum is present when angular momentum is present, but I am more interested in how the conservation laws work out in this situation, since angular momentum and momentum conservation is completely different